# Changing Google account used for auth

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I'm relatively new to the SE forums and it occurred to me that when I setup my account I used my work Gmail account for authentication.  I have no plans of leaving my job at this point but if I ever do I would prefer not to lose my SE accounts as well.  I've looked for a way to change the Google account I use for my SE auth but so far I haven't found anything.  Does anyone know if such a thing is possible?